# How can I change the x-axis label on core-plot Line graph?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-plot

I using a `core-plot` graph library on my project.

but i don't know how can i change the `x-axis` labels, when the line of data will be arrive the end of `x-axis`.

Let me tell you about what I want to do it.

If I display the fifty of data on the graph. the `x-axis` label will like this.
[image: figure: 0 to 50 x-axis appear]

and next, I display the fifty of data on the graph again. so `x-axis` label will like this.
[image: figure: 51 to 100 x-axis appear]

I do the 0 to 50 appear like first figure. but i don't know how to appear the 51 to 100 and 101 to 150 .... like second figure.

I search on google, and I saw the lot of solution, but.. it didn't worked.

I try to this function.

```
CPTXPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph.defaultPlotSpace;

plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(end-length) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(length)];
```

But..it still not working..

Please I need your help.  I wait your answers.

Thank you. Have a good Christmas Day. ^^
Merry Christmas ~^^

Comment: This is not related to your question's answer. but here is very nice library for charts https://github.com/danielgindi/ios-charts

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not working"? Do you get compiler errors? Run-time errors? What version of Core Plot are you using? The plot range API changed slightly with release 2.0.

Comment: Hello Eric!! nice to meet you .
actually "not working" mean is  " It's not the result I want. "
I'm not got a compiler errors and Run-time errors.
I was download the latest core-plot 2.0 at the https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot.

Comment: Is it impossible in core-plot that the results I want?